# How recursion return the value?

Tags: c, function, recursion, return

```
1. #include<stdio.h> 

    int recursion_check(int i);

 
    main(){

         printf("%d",recursion_check(6));
    }
    
    int recursion_check(int i){
    
    if(i==0)
    return 5;
    
    else{
        recursion_check(i-1);
        }
        
    }
```

I am calling a function (recursion check) form main function and getting return value but there is no return in else case how i am getting return value?

Comment: This is just a fluke. Turn on more compiler warnings, like `-Wall` or equivalent, to be informed about potential problems.

Comment: @Carcigenicate for the record, C doesn't require that at all. You can define a function with an `int` type and no `return`, and it will be a valid C program. C++ on the other hand requires a valid return on all code paths inside a function (except `main`, for compatibility with C).

Comment: @Blindy It may be a valid C program, but the results from the function will be indeterminate though right? By "must*, I meant to guarantee expected behavior.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. I mean look at the code in OP. As long as you compile it with a "normal" compiler (gcc, msvc, icc) on a regular platform (x86, x86_64), it will always return the expected value, and it won't write to `rax` the same value on every call. It should generate the correct code that an actual optimizing compiler will output for more portable code, without requiring the optimizing compiler.

Comment: (ignoring tail-recursive optimizations or dead code elimination of course, a fully optimizing compiler should replace the whole call with a load `5` instruction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to undefined behavior.

The reason why it works on your (supposedly) common computer is because register-sized or smaller integer returns on Intel platforms are done by writing to the `RAX/EAX/AX` register, and so most compilers on these platforms will avoid using that register for calculations if they can avoid it.

And so when your function eventually gets to a valid `return` and writes to the `RAX` register, and then returns out of the entire call chain, the function that initially called your recursive function will read `RAX` and it'll get the `5` that was written once.

Of course, nothing stops the compiler from not doing this at all. It doesn't have to use `RAX`, and it doesn't have to avoid using it for other computations. Hence, undefined behaviour.